# Change class style base on what the result is from my record set

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

```html
<p class="fire"><?php echo $row_getPoke['Type1']; ?></p>
```

I want to change the class based on what is going the be viewed on the page.

Basically, if Type1 is "grass" then i want the class to change to class="grass", if Type1 is "fire" then i want the class to change to class="fire", if Type1 is "water" then class="water" and so on and so forth, cant find any results on changing class styles.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to replace `fire` with `<?php echo $row_getPoke['Type1']; ?>`?

Comment: BTW, code snippets are only for complete html/css/js.  php isn't helped by that.

Comment: Placing the PHP inside the class section worked like a charm, thank you!